# How to call an array outside a class using PHP and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, fpdf

hello guys i just need a little help here about accessing a data array outside a class  i'm so confused on how to show the variable outside the class
Here's my code below:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

require('resources/fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {

    function Header(){

        //HERE IS THE PLACE WHERE SHOULD I PUT THE ARRAY, BUT I CANT ACCESS IT INSIDE

        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
        $this->Cell(180,5,'PURCHASE ORDER',0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
        $this->Cell(40,5,'Suppliers Name:'.$data['spname'].'  ');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
        $this->Ln(20);
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM po_order_details WHERE order_code = '".$code."'"; 
$result = $this->db->query($query);
foreach($result->result_array() as $row){
    $data[] = array($row['item_qty'],  //THIS IS THE ARRAY THAT I NEED TO GET
                    $row['spname'], 
                    $row['spaddress'], 
    );
}
$this->session->set_userdata('session_data',$data);
//Column titles
$pdf = new PDF(); 
$header = array('QTY','ITEM / DESCRIPTION' , 'UNIT PRICE', 'TOTAL AMOUNT'); // CHANGE THIS ALSO
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->BuildTable($header,$data);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

that's all i hope you can help me

Comment: try with `$this->session->all_userdata()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: i just try this but it doesn't working  any other idea on  how to call a variable outside the clas

Comment: Guess: $this->Cell(40,5,'Suppliers Name:'.$this->data['spname'].'  ');

Comment: i have tried it already but it doesn't working. $this->Cell(40,5,'Suppliers Name:'.$this->data['spname'].' ');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just change the prototype of your Header method and pass the array as a parameter like this.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

require('resources/fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {

    function Header( &$titles, &$data ){

        //HERE IS THE PLACE WHERE SHOULD I PUT THE ARRAY, BUT I CANT ACCESS IT INSIDE
        // use $titles and $data as you like here

        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
        $this->Cell(180,5,'PURCHASE ORDER',0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
        $this->Cell(40,5,'Suppliers Name:'.$data['spname'].'  ');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',9);
        $this->Ln(20);
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM po_order_details WHERE order_code = '".$code."'"; 
$result = $this->db->query($query);
foreach($result->result_array() as $row){
    $data[] = array($row['item_qty'],  //THIS IS THE ARRAY THAT I NEED TO GET
                    $row['spname'], 
                    $row['spaddress'], 
    );
}
$this->session->set_userdata('session_data',$data);
//Column titles
$pdf = new PDF(); 

$header = array('QTY','ITEM / DESCRIPTION' , 'UNIT PRICE', 'TOTAL AMOUNT'); // CHANGE THIS ALSO
$pdf->Header( $header, $data );

$pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->BuildTable($header,$data);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: i have encounter a problem  i can't solve  
Missing argument 1 for PDF::Header()
Missing argument 2 for PDF::Header()
error 
what am i suppose  to do? any help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you just pass it as a parameter and then return the result?
Like:

```
function Header($param_array = array()) {
  // ... modifications, bla bla
  return $result_array;
}
```

And then look up the function which calls that Header() and pass that array parameter all the way through that function.

Of course, the drawback here is that you would modify FPDF class and would not be able to properly update to an newer version, if you need it at some point in the future.